# Make a dropdown disappear which contains a login form when user logged in

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have been working on this for weeks now trying to find the fix. Here is my problem I have a dropdown bar on my navigation which contains my login. I need it to disappear and be replaced with the welcome message. I can't even get it to disappear the simple way with just the forum

```
if(session is on) {
   view welcome and disappear form
}
else
{
   this is suppose to bring up the form but it doesn't disapear in the first place.
}
```

I don't know if I'm doing this all wrong. Below is the code for my navigation on my php will not post the css. Also the welcome and logout text is within all the other text in the page and I can't seem to move it. It would be nice if I could replace it with the login dropdown. The code is below.

```
//this is the navigation and the dropdown login with the login fourm contained.
<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="messages/message.php">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="ask.php">ASK</a></li>
  <li><a href="cloud.php">Cloud Access</a></li>
   <li><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>

  <ul style="float:right;list-style-type:none;padding-right:150px;">
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="http://google.com" class="dropbtn">Login</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
    <div id="Register">
<form action="" method="POST">
    <p><label>User Name : </label>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /></p>

     <p><label>Password&nbsp;&nbsp; : </label>
     <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" /></p>

    <a class="btn" href="register.php">Signup</a>
    <input class="btn register" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
</div>
</div>
  </div>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>

// this is the php which should make a session and make the fourm disapear. I need the fourm and the dropdown to disapear and be placed with text.
<?php

    if(isset($msg) & !empty($msg)){
        echo $msg;
    }
    ?>

<?php

session_start();
 require('connect.php');

if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
 will be created for the user.
if ($count == 1){
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
}else{

echo "<p id='btn' >sorry please cheach if that is correct .</p>";
}
}

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
echo '<div id="password">';
echo "Welcome " . $username . " ";
echo "<p>This is the Members Area<p>";
echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
echo '</div>';

}else{

}
?>
```

I hope I'm clear of what I said. But if there are any questions please reply below. Thank you and it all make my week if I can get this little problem resolved.

Comment: I don't really understand your question, mate. When exactly do you need the message to disappear? Can't you just use jQuery? Please describe your problem differently and I'll try to help :)

Comment: Not cleaning the username/password before placing it into the SQL query? This is crying for **SQL injections**. I would also recommend using `mysqli_query` since `mysql_query` is depreciated. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php I would also recommend using ajax, this will save the client being navigated from the page to post the form only to find the browser loading the same page again.

Comment: I agree with @NewToJS 100%

Comment: ok how would i change this if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
   header("Location:index.php");
} so that they will be redirected if they are loged in so i can redirect them to the page for people who have already logged in. @NewToJS and how specifically can i help stop geting sql injections and what do they do.

Comment: Do some research on SQL injections, I'm sure you will understand why it's important to clean the data. If you want to speed things up research ajax. This will allow you to post data to the server "server-side page" without moving the client "no need to load /reload pages"

Comment: Your form is hard coded into the file with HTML... There is no way to remove existing HTML with PHP. You should determine whether to display it first before creating it; otherwise, you'll have to look to jQuery to remove elements after the page has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can output the form only if the session variable is not set using PHP,

Example:

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="dropbtn">Login</a>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) // the session variable is not set
{
    ?>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <div id="Register">
            <form>
                // form content here
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```